# `ActiveStorage::Current.host` in test environment (RSpec) returns nil which leads to `URI::InvalidURIError`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

```
Rails 6.1.7
Ruby 3.1.2
Rspec 3.12.0
Capybara 3.38.0
```

While running some tests i call the `ActiveStorage::Blob.url` method to retrieve the url to said attachment. After upgrading to Rails 6.1 i'm getting an error where the url is nil. The test is run in the Capybara/Selenium Chrome driver with Javascript enabled.

The method called is inside a helper module:

```
module ImagesHelper
  def serialised_attachment(attachment)
    {
      downloadUrl:  attachment.url,
      name:         attachment.filename
    }
  end
end
```

When debugging i can confirm that the `attachment` is an `ActiveStorage::Attached::One` and has an associated `ActiveStorage::Blob` to it. This worked before the upgrade.

I've found some issues like this one https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40855 and i've tried to preset the host in the RSpec configuration.

This does not work:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    ActiveStorage::Current.host = "https://example.com"
  end
end
```

This, obviously, does not work:

```
module ImagesHelper
  include ActiveStorage::SetCurrent
  def serialised_attachment(attachment)
    {
      downloadUrl:  attachment.url,
      name:         attachment.filename
    }
  end
end
```

This DOES work, but bad practice and not really doable in production :

```
module ImagesHelper
  def serialised_attachment(attachment)'
    ActiveStorage::Current.host = "https://example.com"
    {
      downloadUrl:  attachment.url,
      name:         attachment.filename
    }
  end
end
```

My conclusion is that somewhere in the test suite the host is set differently since Rails 6.1?

Comment: I got the same problem. I'm looking for a solution too.

Answer (score 1):

I made ActiveStorage, Rspec, Capybara/Selenium and the like to work together by doing so:

```
# config/environments/test.rb
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost', :port => 3000 }

# spec/rails_helper.rb
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.app_host = 'http://localhost'
  config.server_port = 3000
end
```

So, for example, in RSpec system specs I can run:

```
RSpec.describe "Resources", type: :system do
  # ...
  it "should work" do
    expect(page).to have_css("img[src*='#{url_for(@model.attached_image.variant(:thumb))}']")
  end
end
```