# Setting ActiveStorage::Current.host in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In running tests for ActiveStorage I get the following error:

`URI::InvalidURIError`

Several posts pointed to problems if `ActiveStorage::Current.host` being `nil`.

Following the suggestion of several posts I then tried:

1. Setting in rails_helper `ActiveStorage::Current.host = "https://example.com"` according to [the suggestion here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40855#issuecomment-755707529)
2. `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost', :port => 3000 }` according to [the suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75125478/activestoragecurrent-host-in-test-environment-rspec-returns-nil-which-lead)

Both dont work however.

Inserting a byebug right before the test statement, and setting `ActiveStorage::Current.host = "https://example.com"` over there makes the test pass however indicating that the problem is *where* the host is being et.

So my question is, where should I set `ActiveStorage::Current.host` for the tests to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the proper way to fix this issue, but I've solved it (both for test and development) by adding `include ActiveStorage::SetCurrent` into my `ApplicationController`