# How to RSpec system test an Active Storage image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm writing RSpec system specs to test the presence in pages of [Active Storage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html)-powered images. Capybara, Selenium & Co. with a real (non-headless) browser are used.

Actually in my spec file I'm using code like this:

```
it 'image should be present', :js => true do
  ...
  expect(page).to have_css("img[src*='#{url_for(@model_object.picture.variant(:large))}']", :visible => true, :count => 1)
  ...
end
```

Is that the way to system spec test an Active Storage image? If not, how one is supposed to make that?

---

Note: I ask this [because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76079790/824806) I'm getting something that seems flaky testing (flaky tests). In fact, when I run system spec tests individually (`spec/system/model_objects_spec.rb`) then they individually pass; but when I run all them (`**/*_spec.rb`) then the test using the above code fail. And I can't figure out what's going on with fails when running all them, a part the generated error:

```
ArgumentError:
  arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation
```

Comment: tests that fail when run 'en masse' but pass in isolation are the most frustrating to debug. I suggest you put a `debugger` statement to pause the test prior to the failure point, and then probe the page to look at what is actually appearing. Also look at the test.log to see what it is reporting prior to the failure. Using a real (vs. headless) browser can help too.

Comment: Thanks @LesNightingill, I solved _part_ of this problem with routes by adding `RSpec.configure do |config| ... config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` ... end` to the file spec/rails_helper.rb, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9476576/824806).